# Where are Kubernetes' pods logfiles?

Tags: kubernetes

When I run

`$ kubectl logs <container>`

I get the logs of my pods.

But where are the *files* for those logs?

Some sources says `/var/log/containers/` others says `/var/lib/docker/containers/`  but I couldn't find my actual application's or pod's log.

Comment: If your Kubernetes cluster spawns across different nodes you need to look on the node that actually runs the `pod`. Use `kubectl get pods --output wide` to find the right node.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the log file path using:

> docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $INSTANCE_ID